# Computer Ker(L) where L = D - 2x

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, homogeneous-equation

I'm doing homework on "General Theory for Linear Differential Equations" in my Differential Equations and Linear Algebra class and some of the questions are hard to find information on. There is an example problem below that represents the set of problems. I understand the concept of finding the kernel of a linear transformation, and I understand that Ly must equal zero to find it, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to find y to multiply L by. I'd really appreciate a generalized explanation to go with this problem. Here is the example problem:

```
 Computer Ker(L).
 L = D - 2x
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Edit: D is the derivative operator and not a variable.

Comment: For what functions $f(x)$ is $Df(x)$ equal to $2xf(x)$?

Comment: Well the answer is ce^(x^2) where c is an arbitrary constant, but I'm not quite sure how to find the solution systematically for the more complicated problems that can't be seen by observation.

Comment: If $f(x)\in\ker(L)$, then $Df(x)=2xf(x)$. This is a simple differential equation which indeed has the solution you mention. Can you solve this o.d.e.? If you do, you are done. So in general, if your linear operator $L$ involves some derivative, you will have to solve some differential equation in order to get your kernel. Would this be a general problem, or should it be even more general? Does this help?